# git commit showing coding standard is not installed git commit

Tags: git, composer-php, githooks

Currently i am having PSR2 installed which gets invoked while git commit and show the lines which are in not in PSR2 coding standards.

But i want to install PSR12 coding standard, for which i just tried by changing the PSR2 to PSR12 in my pre-commit git hook (./vendor/bin/phpcs --standard=**PSR12** --encoding=utf-8 -n -p $TMP_DIR) but it is showing me following message

**ERROR: the "PSR12" coding standard is not installed. The installed coding standards are PEAR, Squiz, PSR1, PHPCS, PSR2, Zend and MySource**

Anyone having any idea how to install the same for php using composer or any other method for git commit

Answer (score 1):

There is no stable release of `PHP_CodeSniffer` with `PSR12` standard. You need to install phpcs from `dev-master`:

```
composer require squizlabs/php_codesniffer:dev-master --dev
```

Or wait for stable release (probably [3.3.0](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/issues?q=is%3Aclosed%20milestone%3A3.3.0)).

Comment: thanks rob006
which is the lastest PHP_CodeSniffer i can installed?

Comment: Last stable is 3.2.3, but it does not contain PSR12 standard: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/releases